# How to make this work when for all sizes (c++ beginner file input)

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm working on a project that reads input from a text file and inputs it into a 2d array. If I wanted to make it work for all size, should I use a vector. If so, I'm confused about the syntax for the 2d vector.

Or if I should use a dynamic array, can you advise me on that because I haven't worked on them before. 
    // this reads input from a text file and inserts each word of each line onto an array

```
ifstream file(argv [1]);
int length = atoi(argv[2]);
int grid [20][20];
int row = 0, column = 0;

string line;
while(getline (file, line)) {
     istringstream stream(line);

     int x;
     column = 0;
     while(stream >> x) {
         grid[row][column] = x;
         column++;
     }

     row++;
}
```

My main confusion is whether to use a 2d vector or array, and if so, how to start that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the initial declaration (and construction) of array from this:

```
int grid [20][20];
```

to

```
vector<vector<int>> grid; // Now the size is 0x0
```

Then change adding the new value to the inner array (vector) from `grid[row][column] = x;` to `grid.back().push_back(x);` and

And `row++` to `grid.push_back(vector<int>());`

Not that you don't need `row` and `column` variables now at all.

---

The full code transformed to `std::vector` usage

```
ifstream file(argv [1]);
int length = atoi(argv[2]);
vector<vector<int>> grid;
string line;
while(getline (file, line)) {
     istringstream stream(line);
     grid.push_back(vector<int>());

     int x;
     while(stream >> x) {
         grid.back().push_back(x);
     }
}
```

Comment: Right, how do I make this work when its not 20X20... ie, an unknown size.

Comment: Thanks, never used a vector of vectors before so was a little unsure of how to go about doing it. This was a really clear answer, thank you.

Comment: @Marla: Unfortunately, it's fundamentally broken. The inner vector is accessed _before_ it exists. This will result in a runtime crash at best, and subtle bugs later in execution at worst. That's why copy/pasting code from the internet without understanding it _does not work_.

Comment: @Marla: Note that @chris has now updated this answer to fix that problem. You should not use the old version. Click on `edited X ago` to see what has changed.